# Dynamically changing constant values by radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've two radio buttons like

```
<input type="radio" name="pking"  value="pi" id="p1">
<input type="radio" name="pking"  value="pl" id="p2">
<h3 id="daam" class="text-center"></h3>
```

What i'm trying to do is if radio button with `id="p1"` is selected, a javascript variable should get a value of 35 where as it gets a value of 40 in second case,
and calculate a value.
This is the js code

```
$("#p1").change(function () {
    "use strict";
    var pp = 35;
    $('#daam').text("    value is: " + (21 * pp));
});

$("#p2").change(function () {
    "use strict";
    var pp = 40;
    $('#daam').text("    value is: " + (21 * pp));
});
```

The problem is when i select the another radio button, the value printed in heading tag  do not get updated.

```js
var pp;
$("#p1").change(function() {
  "use strict";
  pp = 35;
  $('#daam').text("    value is: " + (21 * pp));
});
$("#p2").change(function() {
  "use strict";
  pp = 40;
  $('#daam').text("    value is: " + (21 * pp));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="pking" value="pi" id="p1">
<input type="radio" name="pking" value="pl" id="p2">
<h3 id="daam" class="text-center"></h3>
```

Comment: First of all, when using `use strict` you have to define variables with the `var` keyword.

Comment: what you mean by the value printed in heading tag do not get updated? its updating

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `change` event for each radio button. You can do it simply like below.

```js
$(":radio[name=pking]").change(function() {
  var pp = this.id == 'p1' ? 35 : 40;
  $('#daam').text("    value is: " + (21 * pp));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="pking"  value="pi" id="p1">
<input type="radio" name="pking"  value="pl" id="p2">
<h3 id="daam" class="text-center"></h3>
```